# Creating a form that looks like a Django change form

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, admin

I want to create a single Django page and corresponding view that looks exactly like a Django Admin changeform but with my own form fields defined. I am new to Django's template language, though have worked with Django server-side. I'm not sure how to define my server-side view (ideally I can iterate through the form and update my data model accordingly, and signal any validation errors as is normally done in admin forms), and the corresponding template.

1. Should I extend admin's change_form.html template? If so, what parts should I overwrite?
2. How do I write the corresponding view to populate this template or other templates?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Should I extend admin's change_form.html template? If so, what parts should I overwrite?

Absolutely not.

> How do I write the corresponding view to populate this template or other templates?

It's all documented.

1. **Make a [form view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs)**, you may also use an app like [django-crispy-forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/d-0/index.html) to get some python-side layout like django admin's fieldsets
2. **Make [inlineformsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets)** for related objects, this is what django's uses for inlines

Comment: Thanks! I will make a formview. How do I write a template that will embed that form in a page that renders to look exactly like a django admin changeform page?